# Should you reference getters in your test methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, getter

Say you have this class:

```
public class MyObj
{
    private int x;

    public MyObj(int x)
    {
        this.x = x; 
    }
    public void setX(int x)
    {
        this.x = x; 
    }
    public int getX()
    {
        return this.x;
    }
    public void addFive()
    {
        this.x = this.x +5;
    }

}
```

and we want to test it

```
public class MyObjTest
{
    @Test
    public void test5AddFive_equals10()
    {
         MyObj obj = new MyObj(5);
         obj.addFive();
         assertEquals(10, obj.getX());
    }
}
```

The question is - is ok that you're calling a getter method in order to test it? What if your getter method was (somehow) broken?

Comment: Seems completely ok to me.  If you didn't call a getter for this, you'd have to break encapsulation somehow, which is not good.  If your getter fails because it is broken, then the unit test just helped you find a broken getter.

Comment: @DWright I think that's acceptable as an answer.

Comment: Why not add an `assertEquals(5, obj.getX());` before the call to `addFive`?